# Making a jar manifest. Where does it come from do I make my own?

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I recently created a simple tic tac toe program and I've been trying to make it into a jar and I using cmd. I manage to get the jar,but when I click it nothing happens. After more research I figure it's a manifest problem as I didn't do anything to it or can even find one. Now this manifest thing has been really confusing me I have created my own manifest several times as just a txt, but that didn't work and I read that it would create it's own manifest, but I couldn't find that anywhere. Can Someone clarify were this manifest comes from or how to create one.

Java code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
public class TicTacToe extends JFrame {

// GUI constants
private static final int WIDTH = 400; // display width
private static final int HEIGHT = 300; // display height

// TicTacToe layout constants
private static final int NUM_ROWS = 3; // number of tic-tac-toe rows
private static final int NUM_COLS = 3; // number of tic-tac-toe columns
private static final int TOTAL_CELLS = NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS;
private static final int MAX_MOVES = NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS; // max number of moves

// TicTacToe image, message and default cell value constants
private static final ImageIcon X_IMAGE = new ImageIcon("images.jpg", ""); // image for X
private static final ImageIcon O_IMAGE = new ImageIcon("O.jpg", ""); // image for O
private static final String GAME_ENDS_IN_TIE = "nobody wins cause blame john wells"; // tie message
private static final String NON_PLAYER_CELL_VALUE = "-"; // "-" is a non player cell

// Private TicTacToe members
private JButton[] cells;
private CellButtonHandler[] cellHandlers;
private String gameWinner;
private int xGoesFirst;
// private int[] press = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
// private String xMess = "Cross for you laymens out there";
// private String oMess = "Naught for you laymens out there";
private String pOne;
private String pTwo;
// private int pOneWins;
// private int pTwoWins;
private int count = 0;

/**
 * Default Constructor
 */
public TicTacToe() {
    // JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    // SWING OPERATIONS
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS));
    cells = new JButton[TOTAL_CELLS];
    cellHandlers = new CellButtonHandler[TOTAL_CELLS];
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_CELLS; i++) {
        cells[i] = new JButton(NON_PLAYER_CELL_VALUE);
        cellHandlers[i] = new CellButtonHandler();
        cells[i].addActionListener(cellHandlers[i]);
        pane.add(cells[i]);
    }

    setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // END SWING OPERATIONS

    // CLASS OPERATIONS
    this.setGameWinner(GAME_ENDS_IN_TIE);
    this.xGoesFirst = 1;
    this.pOne = "X";
    this.pTwo = "O";
    // this.pOneWins = 0;
    // this.pTwoWins = 0;
    // END CLASS OPERATIONS

} // public TicTacToe()

/**
 * setGameWinner
 * 
 * @param who - the game winner as a String.
 */
private void setGameWinner(String who) {
    this.gameWinner = who;
} // private void setGameWinner(String who)

/**
 * getGameWinner
 * 
 * @return the game winner
 */
public String getGameWinner() {
    return this.gameWinner;
} // public String getGameWinner()

/**
 * Entry point of the program.
 * 
 * @param args - <code>String[]</code> of runtime arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Swing is not thread safe, use SwingUtilities#invokeLater
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new TicTacToe();
        }
    });
} // public static void main(String[] args)

/**
 * CellButtonHandler
 */
private class CellButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * actionPerformed
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton pressed = (JButton) e.getSource();

        pressed.setText(TicTacToe.this.getCurrentPlayer());
        // pressed.setIcon(TicTacToe.this.getCurrentPlayerIcon());

        TicTacToe.this.count++;

        if (TicTacToe.this.gameOverWin() || TicTacToe.this.gameOverTie()) {
            System.out.println(TicTacToe.this.getGameWinner());
            winScreen();
        }

        for (MouseListener ml : pressed.getMouseListeners()) {
            pressed.removeMouseListener(ml);
        }
    } // public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

} // private class CellButtonHandler implements ActionListener

/**
 * private String getCurrentPlayer()
 */
private String getCurrentPlayer() {
    this.xGoesFirst = this.xGoesFirst * -1;

    if (this.xGoesFirst == -1) {
        return pOne;
    }

    return pTwo;
} //    private String getCurrentPlayer()

/**
 * getCurrentPlayerIcon
 */
private ImageIcon getCurrentPlayerIcon() {
    this.xGoesFirst = this.xGoesFirst * -1;

    if (this.xGoesFirst == -1) {
        return X_IMAGE;
    }

    return O_IMAGE;
} // private ImageIcon getCurrentPlayerIcon()

/**
 * Checks if the game ended in a win.
 * 
 * @return true if someone has won the game.
 */
private boolean gameOverWin() {
    if (rowChecker() || colomnChecker() || diagChecker()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
} //    private boolean gameOverWin()

/**
 * Checks if the game ended in a tie.
 * 
 * @return true if there are no more moves to be made.
 */
private boolean gameOverTie() {
    if (this.count >= MAX_MOVES) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
} // private boolean gameOverTie()

/**
 * Checks the rows for a win.
 * 
 * @return true if one of the rows contains three X's or three O's.
 */
public boolean rowChecker() {
    int row = 0; // row variable
    int col = 0; // column variable
    String mark = ""; // string to hold the first
                        // button in a row's text value

    while (row != NUM_ROWS) {
        col = row * NUM_ROWS;
        mark = this.getCellText(col);

        if (mark.equals(NON_PLAYER_CELL_VALUE)) {
            row = row + 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (this.cellsAreEqual(mark, col + 1)
                && this.cellsAreEqual(mark, col + 2)) {

            this.setGameWinner("Row Winner: " + mark);
            return true;
        }

        row = row + 1;
    }

    // no win across the rows so we return false
    return false;
} // public boolean rowChecker()

/**
 * Checks the diagonals for a win.
 * 
 * @return true if one of the diagonals contains three X's or three O's.
 */
public boolean diagChecker() {
    int leftToRight = 0; // start at the top left box
    int rightToLeft = 0; // start at the top right box
    int step = 0; // the number of cells to step over
    String mark = ""; // string to hold the buttons mark

    // first we'll start by checking the top-left to
    // bottom-right diagonal
    leftToRight = 0;
    step = NUM_COLS + 1;
    mark = this.getCellText(leftToRight);

    if (!mark.equals(NON_PLAYER_CELL_VALUE)) {
        if (this.cellsAreEqual(mark, step)
                && this.cellsAreEqual(mark, (step * 2))) {

            this.setGameWinner("Diagonal Winner: " + mark);
            return true;
        }
    }

    // next we'll check the top-right to bottom-left diagonal
    rightToLeft = NUM_COLS - 1;
    step = NUM_COLS - 1;
    mark = this.getCellText(rightToLeft);

    if (!mark.equals(NON_PLAYER_CELL_VALUE)) {
        if (this.cellsAreEqual(mark, rightToLeft + step)
                && this.cellsAreEqual(mark, rightToLeft + (step * 2))) {

            this.setGameWinner("Diagonal Winner: " + mark);
            return true;
        }
    }

    // no win on the diagonals so we return false
    return false;
} // public boolean diagChecker()

/**
 * colomnChecker
 */
public boolean colomnChecker() {
    int row = 0; // row variable
    int col = 0; // column variable
    String mark = ""; // string to hold the buttons mark

    while (col != NUM_COLS) {
        row = col;
        mark = getCellText(row);

        if (mark.equals(NON_PLAYER_CELL_VALUE)) {
            col = col + 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (this.cellsAreEqual(mark, row + 3)
                && this.cellsAreEqual(mark, row + 6)) {

            this.setGameWinner("Column Winner: " + mark);
            return true;
        }

        col = col + 1;
    }

    // no win down the columns so we return false
    return false;
} // public boolean colomnChecker()

/**
 * getCellText
 */
private String getCellText(int which) {
    return this.cells[which].getText();
} // private String getCellText(int which)

/**
 * cellsAreEqual
 */
private boolean cellsAreEqual(String mark, int index) {
    return mark.equals(this.getCellText(index));
} // private boolean cellsAreEqual(String mark, int index)

// private class restart implements ActionListener
public boolean winScreen(){
     Container pane = getContentPane();
     pane.removeAll();
     pane.repaint();
     JLabel label=new JLabel(TicTacToe.this.getGameWinner()+" won");
     label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
     label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
     JLabel back=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("moniz_475.JPEG"));
     pane.add(back);
     pane.add(label); 

     return true;
}

} // public class TicTacToe extends JFrame
```

manifest file:

Main-Class: Tic_Tac_Toe.TicTacToe

Comment: If you're doing this by hand (and you are seriously crazy for doing so - IMHO), then, yes, you will need to create your own manifest and ensure that it is included as part of the Jar command.  A better solution would be to use Ant, Eclipse, Netbeans, Intellij...just about anything else :P

Comment: Why am I crazy? It didn't seem to difficult to just use cmd just a few lines of code.

Comment: This is just my opinion (having spend several years doing just this same thing), you have tools available to you to make this simple, as you say, you've been having trouble getting this to work.

Comment: I've downloaded eclipse in a attempt at a quick fix. I opened up my java file in eclipse and I'm trying to export it as a runnable jar, but there are no launch configurations available.

Comment: You'll need to run the program in eclipse once for a launch a nfiguration to be created automatically

Comment: When you say run do you mean with the ant thing? I tried that, but it says I need an ant file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a manifest file to a jar you have to use `jar -cfm` command.

For example you have a manifest file name Manifest.txt which you want to add to your jar `tictactoe.jar` the the command will be.

```
jar -cfm tictactoe.jar Manifest.txt *
```

If you want to mention main class you have to add an entry in the manifest file as follows.

```
Main-Class: <fully qualified name for the class>
```

Also check the default program for jar files is properly configured.

**Update**

Your Java class is not in a package so your manifest file should be.

```
Main-Class: TicTacToe
```

If you want the class in a package then add the package `package tictactoe;` in the first line above the import statements. The in manifest file should be.

```
Main-Class: tictactoe.TicTacToe
```

For more info check [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Comment: I did this, still didn't work. What exactly do I put in the manifest right now i have "Main-Class: Tic_tac_Toe.TicTacToe" also In cmd I'm putting what you put plus the folder I'm keeping the 3 classes inside, is that correct?

Comment: Run the jar file in cmd/terminal using `java -jar jarfile.jar` check what is the error message you are getting.

Comment: OKay I changed it to just TicTacToe and it's still Could not find or load main class

Comment: You have compilation errors in your java code. Please check https://gist.github.com/seenukarthi/6d731effde7e065639d3 for updated code also I added the compilation error there.

Comment: I don't get any compilation errors. I think its because I forgot some imports some how, thats my bad. I updated the question with all the imports

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an IDE? If so most IDEs have the option of directly exporting your Java program as a jar with Manifest created. What you need to have in your META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file is the main method and any dependent libraries in the class path.

Add the following in your MANIFEST.MF file :

```
Main-Class: com.example.MainClass
Class-Path: lib/library.jar
```

Give the full path to the class with main method in Main-Class and any dependent libraries in Class-Path.

Now you can try creating the jar.